# Create Hadoop Sequence File

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I'm trying to create hadoop sequence file.

I successfully creates a sequence file into HDFS, but if i try to read a sequence file, **"Sequence file not a SequenceFile"** Error occurs. I also check a created sequence file in HDFS.

[image]

Here is my source code that can read and write sequence file into HDFS.

```
package us.qi.hdfs;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.ArrayFile;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

public class SequenceFileText {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        /** Get Hadoop HDFS command and Hadoop Configuration*/
        HDFS_Configuration conf = new HDFS_Configuration();
        HDFS_Test hdfs = new HDFS_Test();

        String uri = "hdfs://slave02:9000/user/hadoop/test.seq";

        /** Get Configuration from HDFS_Configuration Object by using get_conf()*/
        Configuration config = conf.get_conf();

        SequenceFile.Writer writer = null;
        SequenceFile.Reader reader = null;

        try {
            Path path = new Path(uri);

            IntWritable key = new IntWritable();
            Text value = new Text();

            writer = SequenceFile.createWriter(config, SequenceFile.Writer.file(path), SequenceFile.Writer.keyClass(key.getClass()),
                    ArrayFile.Writer.valueClass(value.getClass()));
            reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(config, SequenceFile.Reader.file(path));

            writer.append(new IntWritable(11), new Text("test"));
            writer.append(new IntWritable(12), new Text("test2"));
            writer.close();

            while (reader.next(key, value)) {
                System.out.println(key + "\t" + value);
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeStream(writer);
            IOUtils.closeStream(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

And this error is occur.

> 2018-09-17 17:15:34,267 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader
>   (NativeCodeLoader.java:(62)) - Unable to load native-hadoop
>   library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where
>   applicable 2018-09-17 17:15:38,870 INFO  [main] compress.CodecPool
>   (CodecPool.java:getCompressor(153)) - Got brand-new compressor
>   [.deflate] java.io.EOFException:
>   hdfs://slave02:9000/user/hadoop/test.seq not a SequenceFile   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.init(SequenceFile.java:1933)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.initialize(SequenceFile.java:1892)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.(SequenceFile.java:1841)
>     at us.qi.hdfs.SequenceFileText.main(SequenceFileText.java:36)

Comment: Why are you creating a reader and a writer? It looks like you've not created the file yet when the reader is even defined, so that's throwing that error. Break these processes into two separate methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is my mistake. I change some source code.

First, i check file is already exists in hdfs. If there is not a file, I creates a writer object.

And when writer process is done, i check a sequence file. After checking file, i successfully reads a sequence file.

Here is my code. Thanks!

```
try {
            Path path = new Path(uri);

            IntWritable key = new IntWritable();
            Text value = new Text();

            /** First, Check a file already exists.
             * If there is not exists in hdfs, writer object is created.
             * */
            if (!fs.exists(path)) {
                writer = SequenceFile.createWriter(config, SequenceFile.Writer.file(path), SequenceFile.Writer.keyClass(key.getClass()),
                        ArrayFile.Writer.valueClass(value.getClass()));

                writer.append(new IntWritable(11), new Text("test"));
                writer.append(new IntWritable(12), new Text("test2"));
                writer.close();
            } else {
                logger.info(path + " already exists.");
            }

            /** Create a SequenceFile Reader object.*/
            reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(config, SequenceFile.Reader.file(path));

            while (reader.next(key, value)) {
                System.out.println(key + "\t" + value);
            }

            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeStream(writer);
            IOUtils.closeStream(reader);
        }
```